# Can I use Selenium to create automated traffic for improving SEO?

Tags: seo, ranking, automation

Can I use selenium automated traffic for improving SEO of my website?

Because Selenium traffic is shown in Google Analytics, I'm thinking it might be helpful for improving my website's search rankings.

Comment: Of course not! Google analytics has nothing to do with SEO. It is a reporting tool and does not effect the search engine at all. Cheers!!

Comment: If you have to ask this question often the answer is `no`. If you are automating traffic coming from Google or Bing then this would be considered a manipulation of search results. If you are testing just internally then you will be okay.

Comment: Google says they don't use your Google Analytics stats to decide how your site should rank.   Just hitting your own site with fake traffic with do absolutely nothing for SEO.

Answer (score 4):

On using of automated traffic for SEO purposes you will 100% violate against Google terms of service. If you will be caught by Google on this, the penalty probability is very high.

The technical aspects are following:

- to make any use for SEO purposes you should firstly start automatically a search query at google search page,
- than click automatically on you site's url, which is ranking for the queried keyword.
- On browsing you should randomize everything. Everything means:

  - IP
  - MAC address
  - operation system
  - system configuration
  - amount and setup of peripheral devices
  - browser language
  - browser extentions
  - click/surfing pathes (click-through ways you through your website after you visit it from search results page)

The idea behind this is, that higher CTR on Google's SERP page acccompanied by good user metrics after SERP click-out (high time-on-site and time-on-page, deep click-through) causes better rankings. The idea was empirically proven by some researchers.